# QPushButton signal

Tags: c++, qt, clion, qt6

I'm trying to get a QPushButton's action method running doing the following.

My login.h:

```
//
// Created by simon on 28.04.22.
//

#ifndef RESTCLIENT_LOGIN_H
#define RESTCLIENT_LOGIN_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Login; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Login : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT

QPushButton * loginButton;
QLineEdit * passwordInput;
QLineEdit * usernameInput;
QObject::connect(loginButton, &QPushButton::click, this, &buttonPressed);

public slots:
    void buttonPressed();

public:
    explicit Login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~Login() override;

private:
    Ui::Login *ui;
};


#endif //RESTCLIENT_LOGIN_H
```

The corresponding login.cpp:

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_Login.h"


Login::Login(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Login) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Login::~Login() {
    delete ui;
}

void Login::buttonPressed() {
    //todo process login
}
```

The build fails, and Clion marks the code line containing the `connect` method in red. I'm aware that my attempt to connect the signal to my function is wrong, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: "The build is failed and Clion is marking the connect method red" what is the error message you get?

Comment: You could have named the slot `on_loginButton_clicked()` instead of `buttonPressed()` and had Qt autoconnect it for you without the QObject:connect(). Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)

Comment: currently it does not find my ui file, how does I include it?
It's named login.ui and located in the same directory

Comment: ***currently it does not find my ui file, how does I include it?*** You probably need to ask a new different question about this new problem and show your `CMakeLists.txt`. Don't modify this question. It has been solved correctly by both people who have answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `QPushButton::click()` is not a signal, it is a function that performs a click.

The signal emitted when clicking the button is: `QPushButton::clicked()`.

And [as already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72045430/11455384), you should call the `QObject::connect()` function from inside a function (in the constructor for example). It makes no sense to call it in the class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The connect call looks mostly fine, except that `click` is not a signal as [Fareanor first noticed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72045428); use the [`clicked` signal from QPushButton's base class QAbstractButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) instead. See also [QAbstractButton Signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#signals) for all available signals.

Additionally, `connect` needs to be inside of a function, not in the class declaration. The button needs to be initialized for the connection to work, so the constructor of your `Login` class seems like a logical place for it, for example:

```
Login::Login(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Login) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(loginButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &buttonPressed);
}
```

From the code you're showing it seems that `loginButton` is separate from the other GUI stuff in `ui`, so you probably also need to create that button first, i.e., adding `, loginButton(new QPushButton)` after `ui(...)`, or move the loginButton to your .ui file...